# What clues are given in the Handmaid's Tale towards Offred's real name?

Tags: the-handmaids-tale

I read the book four months ago, yet I do not remember if there was any clues regarding Offred's real name. However, the very first episode of *The Handmaid's Tale* series suggested that

> Offred's real name is June.

Understandably, I stopped watching the series, because of this huge spoiler.

- Were there any clues in the first book, i.e., *The Handmaid's Tale*, regarding the real name of Offred?
- Were there any other names in the first book which could have been Offred's name?

Comment: You may wish to note that this revelation is in no way a spoiler

Comment: I do not know if you are joking. Knowing her real name is that much of a deal-breaker for you?

Comment: @Adamant I'll watch them after reading Testaments. Why is it so weird? I was afraid of other testaments materials, that is why I stopped.

Comment: @C.Koca, nothing in the TV series spoils *Testaments*.

Comment: Did you read the historical notes at the end of *The Handmaid's Tale*? Because, at the risk of spoiling you, they kind of spoil *The Testaments* too.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I did, but there is not much to do about it. At least through testaments, I hope that I'll learn how the notes are transferred.

Comment: @C.Koca: the three chapters detailing exactly what it's like to transcribe old cassette tapes were definitely one of the highlights of *The Testaments*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Please don't spoil it intentionally. You already know I haven't read it.

Comment: @C.Koca I do! My last comment may actually be fictional, for that very reason!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is addressed in Atwood's preface to the 2017 edition.

> Why do we never learn the real name of the central character, I have
> often been asked. Because, I reply, so many people throughout history
> have had their names changed or have simply disappeared from view.
> **Some have deduced that Offred’s real name is June, since, of all the
> names whispered among the Handmaids in the gymnasium/ dormitory, June
> is the only one that never appears again.** That was not my original
> thought, but it fits, so readers are welcome to it if they wish.

The passage in question is below.

> We learned to lip-read, our heads flat on the beds, turned sideways,
> watching each other’s mouths. In this way we exchanged names, from bed
> to bed:
>
> Alma. Janine. Dolores. Moira. **June.**

Answer (score 11):

Chapter 1 of the book describes the Rachel and Leah Center where the narrator of the story has been sent for reeducation, along with other potential child-bearing women.  The chapter ends with:

> We learned to whisper almost without sound.  In the semi-darkness we could stretch out our arms, when the Aunts weren't looking, and touch each other's hands across space.  We learned to lip-read, our heads flat on the beds, turned sideways, watching each other's mouths.  In this way we exchanged names, from bed to bed:
>
> Alma.  Janine.  Dolores.  Moira.  June.

All the other women named in this passge, all of them except June, appear later in the story.  If those were the only five women present, then June must be the narrator, Offred.

There are no other unidentified women's names in the rest of the book, so "June" is the only possibility for the narrator's first name for which there is any evidence.